# How to make a field increment by one each time it a change is made via workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a field called "rev" and it starts at 0 however I would like it to increment by 1 each time a change is made via workflow.
What's the best easy to do this?
Should the rev field be text and with a value of 0?
I had it at numerical but it keeps coming up as "double".
I tried "Do Calculation" and also the "Update". I'm certainly missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.

Your 'rev' column should be set to a type of 'Number', but using column settings you can specify this field show integers/whole numbers only by setting the Number of decimal places value to 'None'.

Then, in the WF you can insert the Do Calculation step:

```
then Calculate CurrentItem:rev plus 1 (Output to Variable: result)
```

then update the current list item:

```
then Update item in Current item
```

setting the Update List Item parameters to 'Field': rev to 'Value':  Variable: result

Whilst the Workflow definition will treat the field values as type 'Double' it does not affect the end result.